# CLEANUP and CAPTURE jobs not being created when CDC is enabled in an AOAG setup

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture

We are in the process of upgrading to ENTERPRISE SQL SERVER 2022. The DB is configured with AOAG. When we enable CDC at the database/table level, for some reason, the CLEANUP and CAPTURE jobs are not being created.  But the cdc.tablename are there in system tables.

We never had this issue in STANDARD edition 2019.  Have you encountered this?  Any leads on how to resolve this?

Below is what we see in STANDARD edition but this is not showing in ENTERPRISE EDITION.
[image]

Appreciate your help!

Comment: What is the current version and edition of SQL Server that you're using?